# Solr dih last index time offset

Tags: solr, dih

Solr last_index_time is Solr server machine time when dih is kicking off. If system is distribute with multiple servers, which don't have exact timestamp, how to handle the time difference?

One solution to me is set a tolerance, e.g. 5 mins, when doing dih delta import, minus the above last_index_time by 5 mins. Although some duplicated items will be processed, Solr will override the existing items.

Could you give me some advice? Thanks.

Comment: Do you trigger an import on every servers? Or is there a master-slave setup?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have one database with several app servers attached, so the record updated time in DB is from different app servers. Solr is currently delta importing this DB according to the last_index_time in dataimport.properties and DB record updated time, which might be a little different. How to handle such case? I think it's a common case, unless I mistook Solr mechanism. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way that I have seen this concern addressed is to run DIH on only one Solr instance in the Solr landscape, and then use Solr's replication (aka master-slave as pointed out above) functionality to distribute the updated information around to the other indexes that are involved.

Comment: I have only one Solr instance, since I have only one database now. The point is the only one database stores lastUpdateTime records that come from different app servers (not exact the same timestamp), and this lastUpdateTime is used in dataimport.properties.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I understand the dilemma now.  Other than attempting to normalize the application update times in the database somehow, one straightforward approach might be to treat each logical webapp as a shard (in Solr 4.x, this is easier to use, see http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Shards+and+Indexing+Data+in+SolrCloud); alternatively, you could treat them as separate cores (again based on webapp as a discriminant) and then merge them together (see http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Merging+Indexes).